# How to insert audio plugins on master out of Pipewire

Tags: sound, pipewire

With Pulseaudio routed through Jack, I could send the Pulseaudio audio into the input of a plugin host connected via Jack. I could then insert e.g. an EQ or limiter into the signal chain between the desktop apps and my laptop speakers. This was especially useful when the audio in a browser was too quiet even with the laptop volume at full volume. (So one uses the EQ to cut out frequency content that won't be reproduced by the laptop speakers, and then limit the result to make things louder.)

Is this possible with Pipewire? (I've recently installed 23.10 on a spare laptop, whereas before with 22.04 I was using the Pulse+Jack combo.)